# Restrain form to the working area of the screen without flickering

Tags: vb.net, forms, drawing, screen

I have working code but when moving the form to the screen bounds I sometimes get form flickering. It doesn't look good.

Is there a better solution for this?

```
Private Sub Form1_Move(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
    Dim p As Point
    p = Me.Location
    Dim screenWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
    Dim screenHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
    Dim TaskBarH As Integer = screenHeight - Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height

    If p.X < 0 Then
        Me.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, p.Y)
    ElseIf p.X > screenWidth - Me.Size.Width Then
        Me.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(screenWidth - Me.Size.Width, p.Y)
    End If

    If p.Y < 0 Then
        Me.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(p.X, 0)
    ElseIf p.Y > screenHeight - Me.Size.Height - TaskBarH Then
        Me.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(p.X, screenHeight - Me.Size.Height - TaskBarH)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of restricting where the form can go, try restricting where the mouse can go while dragging the form.

Comment: No, It doesn't matter what's in the form. I would like to restrain form (any part of the form) from exiting the working area of the screen, e.g. when left side of the form (or top) goes to x = 0 then I would like to stop form from moving any further to the left (or up). P.S. Form resizing is fixed.

Comment: @Paul Ishak It's impossible to predict where the user is going to click on title bar of the form, so I wouldn't know in what way to restrict mouse movement.

Comment: It's not impossible. See my example below

Comment: @PaulIshak - While not impossible, that seems like a whole lot of complicated-ness to achieve something so small.

Comment: It's not so complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your form is flickering when you are moving it around, is because every time the form is redrawn in a different location, the `Move` event is fired. To see just how much, try this:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
    Dim counter As Int64
    Private Sub Form1_Move(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
        counter += 1
        Console.WriteLine(counter)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You'll notice that anytime the form is moved even just one pixel, the event is getting fired. You move the form 100 pixels to the left, that event is going to fire 100 times. That's a lot of work to be checking the location on every redraw of the form and then computing if each individual point is within the bounds that you want. All that constant computing of the points and rectangles and such is causing a huge overhead and the result is not enough resource time to redraw all of the controls in the form, hence the flickering of the form.

The better option would be to do all of that math only once when the form is done moving and correct the form if it is outside of the screen bounds. There is a `Form.ResizeEnd` event that is fired anytime the user has finished re-sizing or moving a form. By utilizing this event, the code will only get called once after the user has finished their action and the form has redrawn itself on the screen. Then if the form is outside of the bounds that you want, you can move the form to a location that is.

Rather than hard-coding the use of `Screen.PrimaryScreen`, I am dynamically getting the screen in which the form resides. This allows the user to move the form to a different screen in a multi-monitor environment.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_resizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ResizeEnd
        Dim screenArea As Rectangle = Screen.GetWorkingArea(Me.Location)
        Dim formArea As Rectangle = Me.DesktopBounds

        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal AndAlso Not screenArea.Contains(formArea) Then
            If formArea.Top < screenArea.Top Then Me.Top = 0
            If formArea.Left < screenArea.Left Then Me.Left = 0
            If formArea.Right > screenArea.Right Then Me.Left = Me.Left - (formArea.Right - screenArea.Right)
            If formArea.Bottom > screenArea.Bottom Then Me.Top = Me.Top - (formArea.Bottom - screenArea.Bottom)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I tried this example, and it causes a lot of ugly resizing(windows 10).

Comment: In win10, when you drag a form to the edge of a screen, you get a bubble ping effect, and the form will maximize, or snap to the edge of the screen.

Comment: Well I'm on Windows 8.1, the form never resizes, just gets moved. Unless the mouse is dragged all the way to the edge of the screen, then the Windows Aero Snap thing takes over and snaps the form to the associated bounds, but in that case that's Windows working as expected.

Comment: Wouldn't we be specifically trying to avoid the form overlapping? Saying that it only gets ugly when the user drags the form to the edge is missing the whole point. The whole point is to allow the user to drag the form as far as they want, but restricting the form to stay within the bounds of the working area of the screen, which I guess I could only assume that allowing the form to snap, would be an undesired effect as well.

Comment: My though process was that if the Form snaps to the screen bounds, it's still within the bounds of the screen and fits the desired output of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try restricting where the mouse can drag the form like this.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" (X As Integer, Y As Integer) As Boolean
    Public Function AbsoluteFormMousePosition() As Point
        Dim mousePos As Point = PointToClient(MousePosition)
        Dim hBorderWidth As Integer = (Me.Width - Me.ClientRectangle.Width) \ 2
        Dim vBorderWidth As Integer = hBorderWidth
        Dim TitleHeight As Integer = (Me.Height - Me.ClientRectangle.Height) - vBorderWidth
        Dim newPos As New Point(mousePos.X + hBorderWidth, mousePos.Y + TitleHeight)
        Return newPos
    End Function
    Function TryOffest(range As Range, find As Integer, ByRef newValue As Integer) As Boolean
        If Not range.Contains(find) Then
            Dim diff As Integer
            diff = If(find > range.Upper, find - range.Upper, range.Lower - find)
            newValue += If(find > range.Upper, -(diff), diff)
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Move(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
        Dim mousePos As Point = MousePosition
        Dim newX As Integer = mousePos.X
        Dim newY As Integer = mousePos.Y
        Dim vChanged, hChanged As Boolean
        Dim hBorder As Integer = Me.Width - Me.ClientRectangle.Width
        Dim vBorder As Integer = Me.Height - Me.ClientRectangle.Height
        Dim adjX As Integer = Me.PointToClient(mousePos).X
        Dim adjY As Integer = Me.PointToClient(mousePos).Y
        Dim titleMousePosition As Integer = hBorder - Me.PointToClient(mousePos).Y
        Dim verticalBounds As New Range(AbsoluteFormMousePosition.Y + 2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - (Me.Height - vBorder - adjY + 2))
        Dim horizontalBounds As New Range(adjX + 2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - (Me.Width - hBorder - adjX + 2))
        vChanged = TryOffest(verticalBounds, mousePos.Y, newY)
        hChanged = TryOffest(horizontalBounds, mousePos.X, newX)
        If vChanged OrElse hChanged Then SetCursorPos(newX, newY)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Range
    Public Lower, Upper As Integer
    Sub New(lower As Integer, upper As Integer)
        Me.Lower = lower : Me.Upper = upper
    End Sub
    Public Function Contains(number As Integer) As Boolean
        If number >= Lower AndAlso number <= Upper Then Return True Else Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Since you are Overridding the `OnMove` event and performing quite a bit of variable instantiation, will this not also be plagued by the form flickering that is mentioned in the original question?

Comment: Results may vary. I have noticed less flickering on my PC.

Comment: Also tried your example, which exhibits undesirable side effects as well.

Comment: Sorry, a bit of flickering when form moved to the corners of the screen, but it's hard to notice.